# calling gdal_merge.py into another python script running GDAL processes

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-merge

I want to use `gdal_merge.py` to merge a series of .tif files prior to clipping the merged file to a shapefile boundary, but want to do so as part of another larger script that will execute a number of other processes.  I am a python/GDAL newbie and am not sure how to go about calling `gdal_merge.py` into another script.

I cannot merely run `gdal_merge.py` on its own as it is but one step in a script that will hopefully execute a number of processes. Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site Mike.  As this question stands, I see four questions:  How to generate a list of tiff files?; How to reproject a list of .tiff files? How to clip a list of tiff files?; How to call a script from within a script?.  GIS SE is a focused Q&A site that is best suited for single questions.  Please consider focusing this post into a single question.  For more information on GIS SE, you can take the tour (http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) or access our help center (http://gis.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is by importing the path where `gdal_merge.py` is located, in my case, `/usr/bin/` -- substitute with the path to `gdal_merge` on your system, which, obviously, could be a Windows path too.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/bin/')
import gdal_merge as gm
```

You will now have to build up an array for `sys.argv`, as if you were calling `gdal_merge` directly, e.g.,

```
sys.argv = ['-o','outputfile.tiff','inputfile1.png', 'inputfile2.png', ....'inputfile10.png']
gm.main()
```

There is more information on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

There is also the [`__init__.py` mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), but this requires the file you are importing to be in a sub-directory of wherever you are running your python file from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response John, I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Are you in a position to use gdalwarp instead (depends what you are doing, I guess, but often recommended over gdal_merge). If so, you could use the [suprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) as it is C and not Python. Look particularly at Popen.

Comment: So here's the situation. I have to write a script that will reproject a series of tifs, merge them, and then clip them to a boundary. I have already written a script using gdalwarp to reproject (using the subprocess module per another poster). That said, I now have to pull off the other two steps in the same script and am not sure how to use subprocess for multiple processes. Furthermore, I wasn't aware that gdalwarp could merge a series of files. I'm sure this is fairly simple, but this is all brand new to me.

Comment: gdalwarp input_tiles output_tile will definitely mosaic tiles and you could call it using subprocess also. Unfortunately, we just had a power cut at work and my laptop battery is a bit low, so can't do any testing :(

Comment: Awesome John, thanks. Will gdalwarp need to be called in 3 different subprocesses given that it will be running three different processes (reprojecting 4 tiles, mosaicing the four, and then clipping them) or can all these features be contained in a single line?

Comment: I think you can do all three in one line, but I have never tried. The order or operations presumably matters -- if you are clipping to input or reprojected srid. Think you'll have to test that.

Comment: Rather than modifying `sys.argv` you should use the list as argument for `gm.main`, like `gm.main(['-o','outputfile.tiff', ...])`.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:*

Just read that this option was suggested in the comments already. Anyway, for completeness sake. Maybe someone can merge the answers?

Of course it also possible to use python's `subprocess`, e.g.

```
import subprocess
def merge(first, second, out_file):
    """
    This utility will automatically mosaic a set of images.
    All the images must be in the same coordinate system and
    have a matching number of bands, but they may be overlapping,
    and at different resolutions. In areas of overlap,
    the last image will be copied over earlier ones.

    :param first:
    :param second:
    :param out_file:
    :return:
    """
    ps = subprocess.Popen(
        ['gdal_merge.py', '-o', out_file,
         '-of', unipath.Path(out_file).ext,
         '-n', NO_DATA_VALUE,
         first, second],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    output = ps.communicate()[0]
    for line in output.splitlines():
        logger.debug("[*] {0}".format(line))
```