# Merge tif files with python

Tags: python, gdal, merge

I'm also having problems with running gdal_merge.py within another python script and I cannot run it. I already checked a similar problem [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118987/calling-gdal-merge-py-into-another-python-script-running-gdal-processes/124964#124964). My example is as follows:

First I set my workspace and locations:

```
sys.path.append('C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.2/Scripts/') 
import gdal_merge as gm workspace="D:/Satellitendaten/rapideye/img/testregion/cannyedge/out/"
os.chdir(workspace)
```

Then I run:

```
sys.argv = ['o', 'out.tif', 'allre1.tif', 'allre10.tif', 'allre11.tif', 'allre12.tif', 'allre13.tif', 'allre14.tif', 'allre15.tif', 'allre16.tif', 'allre17.tif', 'allre18.tif', 'allre2.tif', 'allre3.tif', 'allre4.tif', 'allre5.tif', 'allre6.tif', 'allre7.tif', 'allre8.tif', 'allre9.tif']
```

I get:

> 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

But also ERROR 4:

> `out.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

So the output is not created. Maybe someone can help me out with the issue to merge different tif files to a single tif?

Comment: Is there a typo at 'gm workspace'?  Why is it two words?

Comment: Just a thought, setting sys.argv as you are may be causing a problem.  sys.argv[0] is always the path of the current script running.  Whenever I pass in args in this way I usually do sys.argv[1:] = [#your args here].  I should add that when I do that, it is when using ArcGIS/arcpy so it may not apply for gdal.

Answer (score 3):

As  crmackey notes in his comment, the first element in sys.argv needs to be the current script. You also need to use '-o' instead of 'o' as your first argument for [gdal_merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)

Try:

```
sys.path.append('C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.2/Scripts/') 
import gdal_merge as gm 
workspace="D:/Satellitendaten/rapideye/img/testregion/cannyedge/out/"
os.chdir(workspace)

sys.argv[1:] = ['-o', 'out.tif', 'allre1.tif', etc...]
```