# Open source option to ArcGIS tool MosaicToNewRaster_management in python?

Tags: python, raster, image-mosaic

Is there any open source option in python to mosaic rasters to one raster? The equivalent of the MosaicToNewRaster_management in ArcGIS.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with python imaging library or its successor. Open an output image in memory, write chunks to it. Google plus a bit of hacking is your friend here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python use

- [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) -> [Developing Open Source Software for Processing Mosaics](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/rasterio-open-source/)  (see [Comparing Map Algebra Implementations for Python: Rasterio and ArcPy (pdf)](http://www.gis.smumn.edu/GradProjects/Marek-SpartzM.pdf))
- [osgeo (GDAL/OGR](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/2.0.1) -> [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html) and the University courses of Chris Garrad ([Geoprocessing with Python using Open Source GIS](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/): Week 5: Map algebra and writing raster data
- the new [GeoRaster](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/georasters) module
- you can also use gdal_merge.py with the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module
- and the classical packages to manage raster images (in the book [Python Geospatial Development Essentials](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-geospatial-development-essentials) for example)

In the shell, use all the GDAL commands (as Camargo says)

Answer (score 1):

In shell, use GDAL merge

```
% gdal_merge.py -init 255 -o out.tif in1.tif in2.tif
```

In Python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("gdal_merge.py -init 255 -o out.tif in1.tif in2.tif")
```

More info at:
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated, use the  [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module

Comment: see  [calling gdal_merge.py into another python script running GDAL processes](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144972/2581)