# calling gdal_merge into python script

Tags: python, dem, windows, gdal-merge, spyder

I am new to python and breaking my head on how to use gdal_merge in a (spyder) python script. I use Windows 10, Python 3.6 and have the gdal tool installed from osgeo4w. I realize many other posts describe [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118987/calling-gdal-merge-py-into-another-python-script-running-gdal-processes) problem but none could help me resolving this issue.

When i call the gdal module from cmd, it works like a charm:

```
 python "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_merge.py" -o merged.tif input1.tif input2.tif
```

However, I cannot get it working properly in a python script (spyder).

A first approach produces an output but not with the right name: it produces an 'out.tif' file and not the 'merged.tif' file as I request:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin')
import gdal_merge as gm
gm.main(['-o', 'merged.tif', 'N00W078.tif', 'N00W079.tif'])
```

A second approach simply produces no output:

```
import subprocess
merge_command = ["python", "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_merge.py", "-o", "merged.tif", "input1.tif", "input2.tif"]
subprocess.call(merge_command,shell=True)
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add an empty argument in the **first approach** (because `gdal_merge.py` parses arguments starting from 1 and not 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin')
import gdal_merge as gm
gm.main(['', '-o', 'merged.tif', 'N00W078.tif', 'N00W079.tif'])
```

Join the path of `gdal_merge.py` in the **second approach**:

```
import os, subprocess
gm = os.path.join('C:\\','OSGeo4W64','bin','gdal_merge.py')
merge_command = ["python", gm, "-o", "merged.tif", "input1.tif", "input2.tif"]
subprocess.call(merge_command,shell=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10, Python 3.9, QGIS 3.20 (installed with OSGeo4W). This code works fine:

```
import osgeo_utils.gdal_merge
output_file_path = r'insert path here'
input_files_path = r'insert path here'
parameters = ['', '-o', output_file_path] + input_files_path + ['-separate', '-co', 'COMPRESS=LZW']
osgeo_utils.gdal_merge.main(parameters)
```

the -separate flag puts each input in a different band in the raster, if you need the normal merge where the output raster has one band don't use it

```
parameters = ['', '-o', output_file_path] + input_files_path + ['-co', 'COMPRESS=LZW']
osgeo_utils.gdal_merge.main(parameters)
```