# gdal_merge runs indefinitely, crashes system, BSOD

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdal-merge, gdalbuildvrt

I have two small rasters. Same resolution, SRID, type, format. When I use gdal_merge, the console keeps running the command ad infinitum.

```
import time, os

ot = "UInt16"
of = "GTiff"
nodata = "255"
ps = "5 5"
output = r"D:\Tasks_D\merge_minpnt_bris_yate.tif"
input1 = r"D:\Tasks_D\Raster_dev\gdal_sql_minpnt_rec_bris_5m.tif"
input2 = r"D:\Tasks_D\Raster_dev\gdal_sql_minpnt_rec_yate_5m.tif"

merge = fr'gdal_merge.py -n {nodata} -a_nodata {nodata} -ot {ot} -o "{output}" -of {of} -ps {ps} "{input1}" "{input2}"'
print(merge)
os.system(merge)
```

Here is what my console looks like after I run, note that I have to kill the script otherwise it keeps repeating the console command until I get memory issues and even Blue Screen of Death (BSOD):

[image: gdal]

Same issue occurs even if I go the gdal_buildvt route. Either way, I've tried to let this run and nothing happens, just repeating code. This should only take a second or two. I've tried to run this on two other tifs, sometime overlapping tifs, sometimes ones adjacent to each other. No luck. Any ideas on what's happening?

FYI I have a powerful PC with 64GB RAM.

Comment: I guess that you have introduced a loop. Perhaps GDAL autotests give some help with doing it right https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/pyscripts/test_gdal_merge.py

Comment: How could my script cause a loop? It’s a simple merge two files together...

Comment: I don't know what's happening. But I think that this question/answer will help you: [calling gdal_merge into python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/calling-gdal-merge-into-python-script).

Comment: Compare what happens if you run gdal_merge without your own code `python gdal_merge.py -o test.tif test1.tif test2.tif`.

Comment: @user30184 ok so, running `gdal_merge.py` from command line seems to work. I can even run: `gdal_merge.py -of GTiff -ot Byte -n 255 -a_nodata 255 -o "C:\path\test.tif" "C:\path\input1.tif" "C:\path\input2.tif"` so maybe my python install is broken? Or the way I call gdal?

Comment: I believe that your problem is that gdal_merge is itself a python script and you must call it right from python. Have a look at solution that @GabrielDeLuca pointed. I also believe that this question does not have a GIS component and belongs rather to stackoverflow.