# Convert multiple PNG files to one JPEG

Tags: python, mbtiles, png, jpg

Here I have converted a .mbtile file to PNG. The output creates a main folder with multiple subfolders. Those subfolders contain multiple PNGs. I would like to convert all those PNG files to one JPEG image. How can this be achieved? Or is there such existing file?

Comment: You could probably use https://github.com/lovasoa/dezoomify

Comment: @BERA No those are two completely different questions

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/calling-gdal-merge-into-python-script